# Gesture detected which is non targeted by camera

Tags: flutter, flame

I have two worlds A and B.
A has tappable components but B doesn't have tappable components.

First my single `CameraComponent` targets world A and I can detect gesture on the tappable components in A.
Next, my camera switches from targeting world A to world B, then I switch the view to world B.
Finally, When I tap the displayed world B, the gestures are still detected like it would have been world A.

See example here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcpkb.gif

flame: ^1.6.0

I expected that the gestures shouldn't be detected once I swapped to world b, is this not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also remove world A from the component tree if you don't want the gestures to trigger on there.

Just do something like this when you swap the camera to the world B:

```dart
gameRef.remove(worldA);
```